# Filter out preflight/options requests in chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to filter out preflight/options requests in the chrome browser dev tools network tab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you filter the Network pane to "Fetch/XHR" it seems to omit `OPTIONS` request, and mark CORS requests' method as "`GET` + prefetch".

[image: Screenshot of the Chrome Dev Tools Network pane with "Fetch/XHR" filter selected and a red arrow pointing at it.]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not explicit filtering out preflight but in my case but I had enabled `3-rd party requests` and it was covering the *normal* requests. After that, everything was back to normal.

[image]